# SSH in SSH in shell script

Tags: ssh

I'm not sure I have the capability to test this right now, but was wondering if someone might advise if it is possible to do something like this:

```
Run a shell script
    Shell Script SSH's into a machine (Connection requires SSH key only)
        Stuff is run on that machine
        Script run on that machine SSH's into another machine (Connection requires SSH key and password)
            Stuff is run in that machine
            Exit from that machine
        Stuff is run in that machine
        Exit from that machine
    More stuff happens for a few hours
```

Presumably it's just a case of assembling the required level of script and letting it run? To steal an example from another SoF question:

```
sshScript='
    ls -la
    sshScript2=`
        ls -la
    `
    ssh -t ${UserName}@server "${sshScript2}"
    ls -la
'
ssh -t ${UserName}@server "${sshScript}"
```

Where in the case of sudo stuff I just run `sudo -s -u user bash -c script` or whatever?

I'm just unsure if this will result in an endless loop, and as the machines I'm connecting to are in a production environment, I can't afford to risk breaking them for the purpose of testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. But if your script would be longer, I recommend to do this in more commands using `ControlMaster`, as Ansible does it, otherwise you will get lost in all the quotes, backslashes and stuff you can see in your post.

```
scp script1.sh remote:/tmp/
ssh remote "bash /tmp/script.sh"
```

and your `script.sh` can contain one more similar batch from remote machine to another. Also the the script can contain `rm /tmp/script.sh` to clean up itself.

Comment: This is the method I use, though because `script.sh` has been made for this purpose, I usually add the `rm /tmp/script.sh` to the bottom of itself.

Comment: Yes. It is maybe more elegant solution. I will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry, how (in simple terms) does this go about passing the script to each machine? Is it copied over at SSH connection? or in realtime, also, is the script still blocking, and does it mean I need to plant files or remove them manually (comments suggest I have to `rm /tmp/script` for each file I use on each target machine so I'm skeptical of this.

Comment: First of all you prepare your script and by running the `scp` you transfer it to remote server and by `ssh` you will execute. This can dive in recursively. If you leave the `rm` as last command in your script, you don't need to care for cleanup.

Comment: Oh god, I didn't read your original post properly. I see now, and as much as I hate the idea of copying files around in this way it does seem like the best solution. Time to give it a whirl. Thanks.

Comment: I'm now running this solution, but unsuccessfully. Due to security implications, the second nesting of SSH connection needs paired keys and password. I'm actually getting an error: `ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory` followed by some permission denied errors. Do you know how one might pipe the authentification request out to stdout from the "main" console? Or is this not possible? I believe it worked without nesting, out of the box...

Comment: Taking into account that you need to insert password on the way (which was not mentioned in original post!), you can try to add `-tt` switch to your `ssh` commands that should allocate you pseudo-terminal and allow you to enter password.

Comment: I've actually managed to work around it temporarily by disabling the second layer of security, but I'll need to re-enable it once this prototype is ready demonstrated. I'll try the -tt switch at that point and post another question as/when it comes to me. Might even be able to get someone else in the company on it. Now just gotta pass variables down from the top level - presumably I can do this by simply changing the calls to SSH like this: `    ssh -t ${UserName}@server "${sshScript2} $var1 $var2 $var3"`, then extract using $1, $2, $3 and allocate accordingly in the target script?

Answer (score 5):

In such case I usually use heredoc to feed a script to remote shell.  Not usable when script requires user input from stdin, though.

```
ssh ${UserName}@server <<EOF1
ls -la
ssh ${UserName}@server <<EOF2
ls -la
EOF2
ls -la
EOF1
```

Comment: This is elegant solution, but I see potential problem if there is some weird shell that doesn't support newlines in the command like this, ex. tcsh

Comment: Sadly, the script will require user input from stdin, but I appreciate this is a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use "`-q -o "BatchMode=yes"`" option as well as using **public key authentication**.

Also think about single-quoting the command you'd like to run on the remote server to avoid any problem regarding a potential local interpretation of the given command.

E.g : `ssh -q -o "BatchMode=yes" user@server 'ls -al'`

This is a fairly common technique (nested ssh). No problem implementing this.

Comment: Public key authentication already in use, sadly security policies enforce the requirements here, and it must be password + pubkey, which mades life awfully miserable. Looks like roughly what I'll be going for though, depending on the results of passing sh files around...